# API documentation for Gdal/Ogr with C#

Tags: c#, shapefile, coordinate-system, gdal, ogr

I want to assign projection to shapefile in my web C# application, for this i am using Gdal/OGR/OSR C# bindings and add osr_csharp.dll and ogr_csharp.dll references. But i am facing some difficulty while writing the code for assigning projection to shapefile. I want to know is there any API documentation for this which can help me to understand the classes/methods of these libraries.
OR if anybody have some piece of code for assigning projection to shapefile , then it will be great help for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This directory](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/csharp/apps) in the GDAL project tree has some C# examples, specifically [this one](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/csharp/apps/OSRTransform.cs) that might suit your needs.

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT #1:**  *The links below are now dead (left for posterity).*
You can find the GDAL API documentation [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180722025614/http://www.gdal.org:80/hierarchy.html)
There is an GDAL API tutorial [here](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html)
The OGR API documentation is [here](https://gdal.org/api/index.html#vector-api)
The OSR API documentation is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180725030020/http://www.gdal.org:80/ogr__srs__api_8h.html)
All the links you need for OGR/OSR can be reached from [http://www.gdal.org/ogr/](https://gdal.org/programs/index.html#vector-programs)

**EDIT 2:** *This link is still alive but C# info has quietly dissappeared*
All the links you need for GDAL can be reached from [https://gdal.org/](https://gdal.org/index.html)

**EDIT #3**:
[This page](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInCsharp) provides some C# links that still work (as of March 2020) but examples and documentation appears scant.