# DotSpatial.Projections Vs. ProjNET4GeoAPI

Tags: coordinate-system, dotspatial

I have been facing the issue of transform coordinates from a custom spatial reference to a well known spatial reference (let's say WGS84). To do that using ArcObjects is quite straightforward, but I am trying to do it without that library.

I must use some library designed for .NET so making a little research I found **[DotSpatial.Projections](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/)** and **[ProjNet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ProjNET4GeoAPI/)**.

Both of these open source alternatives lack extensive documentation, so some effort is required to understand the process of implementation, although is not all that difficult to.

My question is: In your experience, Which one is better? taking into account ease of use, performance, maintainability (of the library), and support.

Any other suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the grammar correction, please leave the greeting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest working directly with GDAL Dot.Net bindings, thus you can use the whole GDAL C++ documentation.
See this answer for documentation pointers: [API documentation for Gdal/Ogr with C#](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20060/api-documentation-for-gdal-ogr-with-c). With nuget it is also quite easy to use http://www.nuget.org/packages/GDAL/1.10.0.9-a